# how to update div value in mvc 3 without disturbing any other UI values?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC3 with vb.net. I want to update the div value on button click. I know this can do by ajax call to action. but do i need to use partial view for that ? please show me example hint somewhere.

**Edited:** 
I tried with ajax calling. My view is

```
 <% Using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "mycontroller", FormMethod.Get, Nothing))%>
         field 1....
         field 2....
         field 3....
        <%Using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "DailyStatusReport", FormMethod.Get, New AjaxOptions  With {.UpdateTargetId = "textEntered"}))%>
              <span id="textEntered">field4...</span>
              <Html Button to call ajax here on click >
        <% End Using%> 

<% End Using%>
```

while debugging it is executing the the value i wanted. but not rendering. what should be the problem. I tried cache clearing. I want  `"field4"` should change after ajax call.

Comment: what do you want? jquery and ajax? or ASP.net MVC AjaxHelper?

Comment: Any,solution should feasible to render update without disturbing any other page values. any example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do i need to use partial view for that ?

No

@RedSwan - Ajax Calls never disturbs the page as mentioned in below example. Only specific part of the page gets updated.

**Sample Ajax code**

```
$.ajax({
    url         :   "@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")",
    contentType :   "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType    :   "json",
    type        :   "GET",  //In case of non complex data only.
    data        :   JSON.stringify({Param1:'test'})
}).done(function(Result) { 
   // Update the Div here
})
.fail(function() {
});
```

Comment: and what should be in view ? also do i need to write different action for ajax call in controller which will calculate only div vale?

Comment: **and what should be in view ?** Keep a test div in view. **also do i need to write different action for ajax call in controller which will calculate only div vale?** Yes.